# Cannot add Maven archetype in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, karate

I'm trying to create a new Karate project in IntelliJ, and am attempting to add an archetype to the Maven list. However, when I enter all the required fields, the window just disappears and the list of archetypes is unchanged. I've found that this is the same for any value I enter into the fields, not just the ones for the specific archetype I am trying to create. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Please check exactly what you are entering? Can I use these steps to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, this is the first time I've heard of this problem. It will be great if you can contribute research or code to fix this, and I'll gladly take requests to update the documentation.

As a workaround, I suggest you create a project using the maven command-line as described here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the *karate archetype* by using an older version of IntelliJ. The older version I have tried is **IntelliJ Community Version 2021.1.3**
you can find it and download it here based on your Operating System.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html

After that, I just *added the karate archetype* into that version *2021.1.3 IntelliJ*.
Then *launch the latest IntelliJ*.

If you were to make a new Project, with karate Archetype, on the latest version of IntelliJ that I have now **IntelliJ Community Version 2021.2.4** It won't be shown there. Although the project is running on karate.

Answer (score 0):

When windows disappears try close and re-open New Project, then you can choose archetype from list